# Form2.ShowDialog doesn't pause Form1

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

I have a weird problem. Whenever i call my second form the first one doesn't pause

```
private void bHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Help helpMenu = new Help(this);
   helpMenu.ShowDialog();
}
```

i have a progress bar and some timers which keep ticking while `Help` is still being shown. If this is not the way to pause the form anyway how can i do it ?
Im currently pausing all the timers in order to make it look like pausing

Comment: ShowDialog() *only* disables input.  Mouse and keyboard.  Everything else keeps ticking.  Read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/17034) to understand why.

Comment: Thanks i will take a look at it but how can I stop the other things without doing it manually ?

Comment: @kopelence - You need to do it manually - or, at least, you need to create some sort of mechanism that does it for you. You would need to show us the other code to get any more help from us. That would mean posting a new question.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info i took a look at the link @HansPassant posted also checked some stuff on the internet now i have a better knowledge of what's actually going on. If i create some mechanism it will only make it more complex i have 2 timers and a few more things i need to shut off and resume after so i will just keep it simple.